# 0-1 Knapsack: return weight and maximum value in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

We know in 0-1 Knapsack problem we get the maximum benefits from some items with limited capacity. ([Knapsack problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/)).

```
Example:
4 10 // 5 items, 10 capacity
1 120 // weight cost_value
4 280
3 150
4 200
Ans: 600
Total Weight: 9
```

But my question is, I want the total weight and benefit at a time. How is this possible? And what will be the change of my code? Please suggest me with my own code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_N 100
#define MAX_W 1000
int n;
int dp[MAX_N+1][MAX_W+1];
int weight[MAX_N+1];
int cost[MAX_N+1];
int CAP;
int func(int i,int w)
{
    if(i==n+1) return 0;
    if(dp[i][w]!=-1) return dp[i][w];
    int profit1=0,profit2=0;
    if(w+weight[i]<=CAP)
        profit1=cost[i]+func(i+1,w+weight[i]);

    profit2=func(i+1,w);
    dp[i][w]=max(profit1,profit2);
    return dp[i][w];
}
int main()
{
    memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&CAP);
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&weight[i],&cost[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n",func(1,0));


}
```

Comment: Have you implemented this program yourself? Because it is rather ...trivial...

Comment: After filling the dynamic programming matrix you need to go backward through it to establish which items are in the knapsack in the optimal solution...

Comment: I don't understand the question; to my understanding, all necessary information is contained in the array `dp`.

Comment: Actually I want to return both at a time. I can imagine it's needed pair. But I can't to do it in code. For more, I'm not so much expert in dp. I just can solve normal dp problem. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand the question. Do you want to produce output like in your first block of "code"? What's the "normal" dp problem and what's not normal?? Is your question c++ related or DP related?

Comment: Question is dp related. I'm not finding anything which is tough to understand.

Comment: Off topic, but I think this question should be tagged C and not C++, except the using directive at the beginning the code is very un-C++-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem. You have to use pair.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define PP pair<int,int>
int n,target;
int cost[102], weight[102];
int CAP;

pair<int,int> Knap(int i,int w)
{
    if(i==n+1) return make_pair(0,w);
    pair<int,int> profit1, profit2;

    if(w+weight[i]<=CAP) {
        pair<int,int> tmp = Knap(i+1, w + weight[i]);
        profit1 = make_pair(tmp.first+cost[i], tmp.second);
    }
    else
        profit1 = make_pair(0,0);

    profit2=Knap(i+1,w);
    return max(profit1, profit2);
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        cin>>CAP;

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d %d",&weight[i],&cost[i]);
        }
        pair<int,int>P;
        P=Knap(1,0);

        cout<<P.first<<" "<<P.second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
1
4 10
1 120
4 280
3 150
4 200
Ans: 600 9
```